# Force browser to download PDF document instead of opening it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make the browser download a PDF document from server instead of opening the file in browser itself. I am using C#.

Below is my sample code which I used. It not working..

```
string filename = "Sample server url";
response.redirect(filename);
```

Comment: Why not? What happens? What's the actual URL?

Comment: @SLaks.. thanks for reply..it is opening in another tab in browser. not downloading.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should look at the "Content-Disposition" header; for example setting "Content-Disposition" to "attachment; filename=foo.pdf" will prompt the user (typically) with a "Save as: foo.pdf" dialog, rather than opening it. This, however, needs to come from the request that is *doing the download*, so you can't do this during a redirect. However, ASP.NET offers `Response.TransmitFile` for this purpose. For example (assuming you aren't using MVC, which has other preferred options):

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

Comment: thanks for reply... if i give a url instead of foo.pdf in ur answer will it work...?

Comment: @Neon no; you actually need to transmit the contents if doing this; `TransmitFile` takes a *local* file path, IIRC.

Comment: @Neon to clarify - if the URL is somewhere else, you could act as a *proxy* to that URL; but you cannot say "go and get the file from [over there], and treat it as a download" - the server that provides the final content gets to choose the content type and disposition.

Comment: then what i must do to download the file from a url.. is there is anyother method instead of using TransmitFile

Comment: @Neon yes - but it depends on the size; if the expected size is small, just use `WebClient` to get the bytes (`client.DownloadData(url)`), then use `Response.BinaryWrite(blob)` to send it onwards. If the expected size if large, you'd need to do that in a loop using a `HttpWebResponse` - more complex.

Comment: Actually file size may vary. both small sized file and big sized file.

Comment: @Neon then assume the worst and setup a read/write proxy loop from a remote request, throwing the data over in small chunks (using, say, a 10k buffer).

Comment: What would be the preferred options using MVC? Thanks

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes `return File(filePath, "application/pdf", "foo.pdf");`

Comment: @MarcGravell please can you updated your answer to include the preferred options for the MVC

Comment: @MarcGravell: while downloading it locally i am getting `access denied error` even after unchecking the read only part and allowing access to all users. why ?

Comment: I get "Thread has been aborted" error, but it still attempts to open an Outllook MSG file, but it's called it "H_Visual" without an extension. What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to render the file(s) so that you could save them at your end instead of opening in the browser, you may try the following code snippet:

```
//create new MemoryStream object and add PDF file’s content to outStream.
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

//specify the duration of time before a page cached on a browser expires
Response.Expires = 0;

//specify the property to buffer the output page
Response.Buffer = true;

//erase any buffered HTML output
Response.ClearContent();

//add a new HTML header and value to the Response sent to the client
Response.AddHeader(“content-disposition”, “inline; filename=” + “output.pdf”);

//specify the HTTP content type for Response as Pdf
Response.ContentType = “application/pdf”;

//write specified information of current HTTP output to Byte array
Response.BinaryWrite(outStream.ToArray());

//close the output stream
outStream.Close();

//end the processing of the current page to ensure that no other HTML content is sent
Response.End();
```

However, if you want to download the file using a client application then you'll have to use the [WebClient class](http://www.thereforesystems.com/code-sample-programmatically-download-file-using-c/).

Comment: i am getting "Argument Out Of Range Exception" while executing in the line Response.BinaryWrite(outStream.ToArray());

Comment: Have you filled the contents in the outStream? Read your file into the memory stream and I hope it'll be working fine.

Comment: Please try this snippet to convert file to MemoryStream: using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
      MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
      outStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
      fileStream.Read(outStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
}

Comment: Your "WebClient class" is off!!

Answer (score 3):

I use this by setting inline parameter to true it will show in browser false it will show save as dialog in browser.

```
public void ExportReport(XtraReport report, string fileName, string fileType, bool inline)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    Response.Clear();

    if (fileType == "xls")
        report.ExportToXls(stream);
    if (fileType == "pdf")
        report.ExportToPdf(stream);
    if (fileType == "rtf")
        report.ExportToRtf(stream);
    if (fileType == "csv")
        report.ExportToCsv(stream);

    Response.ContentType = "application/" + fileType;
    Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", stream.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename={1}.{2}", (inline ? "Inline" : "Attachment"), fileName, fileType));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
    //Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());

    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if we are trying to write a bytes array then we can use below one.

```
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf");
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", docBytes.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(docBytes);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score -2):

They are almost same in most of the cases but there is a difference:

Add Header will replace the previous entry with the same key

Append header will not replace the key, rather will add another one.