# how to download a file from my desktop .net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

after a long search on the net I did not find a solution how I can do when I click on a document starts its download in the browser ,I need this in my application .net core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force browser to download PDF document instead of opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590543/force-browser-to-download-pdf-document-instead-of-opening-it)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

first, set your response mime type:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf"); //for example
```

second, set following header as a dictate to browsers to download file:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf"); //for example
```